# ASP.NET Custom control, is it possible to restrict contents of a template?

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

Some ASP.NET controls only permit items of certain types, for example:

```
<uc:MyControl runat="server"....>

<MyTableTemplate>
  <MyTableRow .... />
  <MyTableRow .... />
  <MyTableRow .... />
</MyTableTemplate>

</uc:MyControl>
```

I'm trying to recreate this in my own custom control, such that you can only put MyTableRow objects into the template and Visual Studio will prevent the designer putting anything else in.

I've been looking at the [ControlBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.controlbuilder.aspx) class but I am not fully certain it does what I want. In addition the examples do not mention the nesting I have above where the array of MyTableRow is within another template field.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Edit: The UpdatePanel seems to work this way: If you declare an UpdatePanel like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel>
<Triggers>

</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

You cannot put anything in the Triggers section other than the two specific controls listed in intellisense, and you get a design-time error if you try. This is the exact behaviour I wish to mimic.

====

I tried to implement Alex's suggestion, here is my code:

```
public partial class MyControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public ActionButtonCollection ActionButtons
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}


public class ActionButtonCollection : Collection<ActionButton>
{

}

public abstract class ActionButtonBase
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
}

public class ActionButton : ActionButtonBase
{

}
```

However with this code there is no intellisense inside

```
<uc:MyCustomControl runat="server">
<ActionButtons>

</ActionButtons>
</uc:MyCustomControl >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** added a link to the example of doing this to [google docs](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B2z9c2WRBmDbYTIzYTE3NTAtOWYwMC00YWI3LWIwMzYtN2ZlMzAwNGNlZjY4&hl=en).

Firstly, build the website and then you'll be able use this control with IntelliSense.

Actually, `<Triggers>` property of `UpdatePanel` is not a template. It is just a collection of objects. You could achieve this by declaring you own class and a class which inherit `Collection<YourClass>`; then just add the public property of `Collection<YourClass>` type to your control and you will be able to archive the "update panel triggers" behaviour.

Here is an example:

```
public abstract class UpdatePanelTrigger
{
    public string ControlId { get; set; }
}

public class UpdatePanelTrigger1 : UpdatePanelTrigger
{

}

public class UpdatePanelTrigger2 : UpdatePanelTrigger
{

}

public class UpdatePanelTriggerCollection : Collection<UpdatePanelTrigger>
{

}
```

and finally, your control:

```
public class MyControl : WebControl
{
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public UpdatePanelTriggerCollection Triggers { get; set; }
}
```

then you could use it on your page:

```
<my:MyControl runat="Server">
    <Triggers>
        <my:UpdatePanelTrigger1 ControlId="ctrl1" />
        <my:UpdatePanelTrigger2 ControlId="ctrl2" />
    </Triggers>
</my:MyControl>
```

BTW, you cannot put anything to the `Triggers` section other than types which inherit from the `UpdatePanelTrigger` class.

Comment: I've tried this but when I put the cursor in between <Triggers> and type < I don't get any intellisense to add some UpdatePanelTriggers

Comment: Aha, I needed `[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]` around the `Collection<UpdatePanelTrigger>`, so instead of inheriting from it I added it as a property.

Comment: I can't access the property ControlId though

Comment: It doesn't do that for me, also there is no property on ActionButton called test...

Comment: @Alex: I'm not sure... I get ActionButton if I make the collection [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)] but it still doesn't have any properties on it. I'm using .NET 4 too, that's the only other difference I can think of.

Comment: @SLC: I think I've got the point - I also added `<add tagPrefix="my" namespace="Web" assembly="TestLibrary" />` section to the my `web.config` file (`configuration/system.web/pages/controls` section). If this doesn't help, I'll provide a full solution.

Comment: @Alex: I haven't put it into a library project, I don't really want to do that...

Comment: I've done some more hunting around, and it looks like you HAVE to compile it into a DLL to be able to do this...

Comment: @SLC: yes, I added these controls to class library(dll) as I mentioned above. But I works even without adding them to dll. Wait a second, I'll post a link to my project.

Comment: @Alex: Thanks for the massive amount of help you gave me with this, especially the sample project which helped. I tried many things to `<%@ Register` my code but it didn't work until I moved it into a separate assembly, after which it worked perfectly. I don't understand why it had to be a separate assembly, but I am delighted I got it working. Thanks again!